# How can I do to view all items in the twig?

Tags: symfony, twig, symfony5

I am trying to display the information like this:

Controller:

```
public function index(RestaurantRepository $restaurantRepository)
{
    $restaurant = $restaurantRepository->findAll();

    return $this->render('restaurant/index.html.twig', [
        'restaurant' => $restaurant
    ]);
}
```

twig:

```
{% for restaurants in restaurant %}
    {{ restaurant.name }}
{% endfor %}
```

Error "Key" name "for array with keys" 0, 1, 2, ..... "does not exist. But if I type in twig restaurant [0] .name etc it will show me the name in the given index.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You have to use `restaurants.name`, in php is `foreach (collection as item)` in twig it is `for item in collection`.

Comment: In twig it's `{% for value in collection %}`, also you might want to change your variable name `restaurant` to `restaurants` in your controller

Answer (score 2):

It is a problem of plurals.

In your controller, restaurant is a collection, you should replace
`$restaurant` by `$restaurants` and `'restaurant' => $restaurant`
by `'restaurants' => $restaurants`

In twig the problem is here `{{ restaurant.name }}` instead `{{ restaurants.name }}`
So you should replace

```
{% for restaurants in restaurant %}
    {{ restaurant.name }}
{% endfor %}
```

by

```
{% for restaurant in restaurants %}
    {{ restaurant.name }}
{% endfor %}
```